# Repos Didn't Remove. What Repositories to Remove After Upgrade?

Tags: apt, package-management, upgrade, updates, repository

I just upgraded to Ubuntu 22.04, and it crashed during the upgrade and I had to fix it by going to the TTY and running `sudo apt upgrade`, `sudo apt dist-upgrade`, `dpkg --configure -a`, and things like that. Now I am running 22.04 on GNOME 42 and lots of things seem fine. But, there are still old 20.04 repositories that the installer didn't remove at the end (because it crashed).\

The below image shows that there are a lot of weird repos like 3 "important security updates," 2 "recommended updates," and a few 20.04 ones.

[image]

Which repositories do I remove, and which ones do I enable so I can get updates? I do have the universe and everything enabled (below image).

[image]

Which repositories do I remove and which do I enable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are three tabs to pay attention to:

**Ubuntu Software Tab**

After install, all of these boxes are optional. You will use them only for installing new software. None open any security holes, so you can leave them checked if you wish.

- If you don't compile software from source, then it's safe to leave "source code" unchecked.

**Other Software Tab**

These are sources YOU added. None are included in a stock install of Ubuntu. All can remain unchecked (or deleted) without harm to the Ubuntu OS that you installed.

If you installed third-party sources that intend to push upgrades to you, then enable (check) those sources. If you do not remember why you added a source, time to disable (uncheck) that source.

If you don't use that software anymore, or if the name includes an different/older release of Ubuntu, disable that source to prevent conflicts.

- If you don't compile software from source, then it's safe to leave any "source code" boxes unchecked.

**Updates Tab**

You should subscribe to "security and recommended updates". The frequency of those updates is your choice.